# Writing udev rules

Tags: linux, rhel-5, udev, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have added the rule

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/00-my.rules 
ACTION=="add",    KERNEL=="sd[a-z]", SUBSYSTEM=="block", PROGRAM="/usr/sbin/mytool add %r/%k"
```

on my `RHEL 5.8` to check the disk's partition table on disk appearance event.

After I connect the disk `mytool` is called by `udev` subsystem and `udev` is pass something like `/dev/sdb` to `mytool`. But `mytool` unable to `fopen` the `/dev/sdb` because there are no `/dev/sdb` file at the time of `mytool` executing by `udev` on `RHEL`.

How can I `fopen` the file `/dev/sdb/` in mine `mytool`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You should be using `RUN`, not `PROGRAM`.](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#external-run)